# Linear recurrence relations with absolute-constant coefficients

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

What is known about systems of linear recurrence relations
$$X_{n+1}=A(n)X_n$$
where all $|A_{ij}(n)|$ are constants? Can the theory for systems of linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients be extended somehow?

Comment: I believe the change of sign of some matrix elements can do _unpredictable_ things to the eigenvalues.

Comment: Already I don't know anything about this problem for $2$-dimensional matrices all of whose entries are $\pm 1$. Multiplying different matrices is much harder than taking powers of a single matrix.